# Elasticsearch illegal state exception on most basic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got the most basic Elasticsearch query:

```json
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user_id": 123456
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "catalog_ids": [4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 18, 28, 29, 73, 183, 1035, 1037, 1176, 1782]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 20,
  "from": 0,
  "sort": {
    "updated_at": "desc",
    "created_at": "desc"
  }
}
```

And this would respond with partial and failing results:

```json
{
  "took": 943,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 12,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 7,
    "failures": [
      {
        "shard": 2,
        "index": "index_name",
        "node": "tRhSaDIjTLiEAZFSLqGyAw",
        "reason": {
          "type": "illegal_state_exception",
          "reason": "topDocs already consumed"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 8,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

There are hits coming back, I've just removed them to make response easier to read.

This is the mapping:

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "false",
    "_source": { "enabled": false },
    "properties": {
      "catalog_id": { "type": "keyword", "eager_global_ordinals": true },
      "catalog_ids": { "type": "keyword" },
      "created_at": { "type": "date" },
      "price": { "type": "scaled_float", "scaling_factor": 100.0 },
      "sorting_order": { "type": "long" },
      "user_id": { "type": "keyword" },
      "updated_at": { "type": "date" }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "search": {
        "slowlog": { "level": "info", "threshold": { "fetch": { "trace": "300ms" }, "query": { "trace": "300ms" } } }
      },
      "refresh_interval": "30s",
      "number_of_shards": "12",
      "unassigned": { "node_left": { "delayed_timeout": "10m" } },
      "number_of_replicas": "5"
    }
  }
}
```

- Elasticsearch 7.9.3
- Low level cancellation is on
- Cluster timeout is set to 100ms
- Index is fresh and created a couple of days ago
- Index contains 270M documents and primary shards weight about 30G
- Removing at least one `catalog_id` from filter makes things fly and queries respond within 10ms

I tried looking up what could be the potential issue and everything I was able to find was related to top hits aggregations, nothing with the most basic queries.

What could be the potential issue of such a light query being so low and raising that kind of exception?

Comment: We see the same sometimes, however it seems to be intermittent, did you find out why this happened for you?

Comment: We've increased the number of shards and also increased the timeout value, 100ms might have been too aggressive. But that's really it, seemed to solve the issue, but didn't dig deeper into the root cause.

Comment: Thanks, we concluded the same, seems to be a side-effect/bad handling of running into a timeout.

Comment: @centic turns out to have been a bug. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/72661 it was related to an aggressive timeout, but wasn't handled properly .